# Error HTTPError Response from Microsoft Edge

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having issues with this error in angular/typescript.  I have no compilation errors but have issues when I delete things from the database. The error below is from Microsoft Edge debugger. I have tested the delete function via Postman and there are no issues

[image]

In contact.service.ts

```
 deleteContacts(id)
  {
   
    
    let URI = 'http://localhost:3000/api/contact';
    return this.http.delete<{tasks: Task[]}>(URI+id)
    .pipe(map(res => res.tasks));
  
  }
```

In contact.component.ts

deleteContact(id)
{

```
var contacts = this.contacts;
this.contactService.deleteContacts(id)
.subscribe((data:any) => 
  {
    if(data.n==1)
    {
      for(var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++)
      {
        if(contacts[i]._id ==id)
        {
          contacts.splice(i,1);
        }

      }
    }
  }
  );
```

}

Comment: Please expand the error in the console and check any validation error exists? Also check in the Network tab to confirm whether api call is going correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please pass / after contact in the api

```
 return this.http.delete<{tasks: Task[]}>(`${URI}/${id}`)
    .pipe(map(res => res.tasks));
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but when I go to the network tab it's going to http://localhost:4200/$%7BURI%7D/$%7Bid%7D. It suppose to go to http://localhost:3000/api/contact. I'm not sure where to check anymore, in the console window, there's no sign of validation error

Comment: You might have used single quote for string. Please use template literals [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
not single quotes('), you have to use backticks (`)

Comment: Hi, thank you but when I delete, I get this "Cannot read property 'n' of undefined". From the In contact.component.ts file. I guess the data.n part has a problem ?

Comment: `if(data.n==1)` here do `console.log(data)` and check if your response contains `n`.
From API response you are expecting `n` which is not available. That's why this error is showing.

Comment: Now I get error 404. statusText: "Not Found"
url: "http://localhost:3000/api/contact//6125f0a21257d432080cfbe9". The delete is getting the right ID but not sure why there's a problem. The delete is working perfectly in postman

Comment: Because you are passing 2 slash in URL I think. `let URI = 'http://localhost:3000/api/contact` this is your url string rit. Or is it like `let URI = 'http://localhost:3000/api/contact/`. If it is like the second one `${URI}${id}` is enough